# FS - Use FS for Electron on Webpack 5

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, electron, quasar-framework

I recently upgraded my Quasar framework to v2 which uses Vue3, Electron 16 and Webpack 5.

When I tried to run my application, I keep getting this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "fs"
```

I understand that webpack 5 does not automatically do polyfills so I added these in my quasar.conf.js:

```
      chainWebpack (chain) {
        const nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin')
        chain.plugin('node-polyfill').use(nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin)
      }
```

But this doesn't support polyfills for the `fs` module.

When I tried adding this:

```
        if (!cfg.resolve.fallback) {
          cfg.resolve.fallback = {}
          cfg.resolve.fallback.fs = false
        }
```

Now I get an error:

```
TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

I also tried adding this in my package.json, same behavior (as expected):

```
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```

But then.. How can I use `fs` in my electron application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to figure it out now.
Adding it here in case anyone might need it in the future. I see a lot of people asking this question but got no resolution.

So.. I added this to electron-preload.js, since fs / built-in node modules are accessible via the renderer:

```
import { contextBridge } from 'electron'

const fs = require('fs')
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronFs', {
  readFileSync: fs.readFileSync,
  existsSync: fs.existsSync
  // Other fs methods here
})
```

And use it like this in Vue / JS / modules:

```
const fs = window.electronFs
const jsonContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(SOME_PATH))
```

Comment: Where is "electron-preload.js" exactly?

Comment: "electron-preload.js" could have a different name such as just "preload.js" or "preload.ts" if using TypeScript

Comment: For more informations: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload

Answer (score 2):

You can solve **Can't resolve imported dependency "fs" error** by adding the code below to **"build" section** in **quasar.conf.js**:

```js
extendWebpack(cfg) {
  cfg.resolve.fallback = {
    fs: false
  }
}
```

**quasar.conf.js:**

```js
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
    build: {
      extendWebpack(cfg) {
        cfg.resolve.fallback = {
          fs: false
        }
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

In addition, if there are more **Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto", "Buffer", "os", "path", "stream", "assert" and so on**, you can add them as shown below:

**quasar.conf.js:**

```js
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
    build: {
      extendWebpack(cfg) {
        cfg.resolve.fallback = {
          fs: false,
          crypto: false,
          Buffer: false,
          os: false,
          path: false,
          stream: false,
          assert: false,
          dns: false,
          net: false,
          tls: false,
          http2: false,
          https: false,
          http: false,
          zlib: false
        }
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

**"node-polyfill-webpack-plugin"** cannot cover all **Can't resolve imported dependency "xxx" errors** and if you fully use my solution above, you don't need to use **"node-polyfill-webpack-plugin"**. In other words, you can use **"node-polyfill-webpack-plugin"** to cover some parts of **Can't resolve imported dependency "xxx" errors** then for the rest of **Can't resolve imported dependency "xxx" errors**, you use my solution above so you can use **2 solutions** at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new flag in Webpack 5 to target the build for Electron, which includes the correct support.
Simply add `target = 'electron-main'` to your webpack config.

See more here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/